# Match case between three columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, match, tidyverse

Thank you in advance for your time reading this post.
I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
data = data.frame(time=c(rep(c(0,1,2),each=3)),
                  parent=c(1,2,3,1,1,2,1,4,5), offspring= c(NA,NA,NA, 4,5,6,7,8,9))

time parent offspring 
 0     1       NA
 0     2       NA
 0     3       NA
 1     1        4
 1     1        5
 1     2        6
 2     1        7
 2     4        8
 2     5        9
```

I want to create a new column, "alpha" and assign
to the offspring of the last time point (aka time point 2) the value "1".

```
time parent offspring  alpha
 0     1       NA        NA
 0     2       NA        NA
 0     3       NA        NA
 1     1        4        NA
 1     1        5        NA
 1     2        6        NA
 2     1        7        1
 2     4        8        1
 2     5        9        1
```

The tricky part for me is the next step.
I would like to assign the parents of those offspring
also with the value "1" as well as their grandparents and
my data frame to look like this.

```
time parent offspring  alpha
 0     1       NA        1
 0     2       NA        NA
 0     3       NA        NA
 1     1        4        1
 1     1        5        1
 1     2        6        NA
 2     1        7        1
 2     4        8        1
 2     5        9        1
```

I have to tell you that I have thousands of generations.
Any help and comment would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have lots of generations, you might need a loop

```
## set alpha to 1 if time == max(time)
data$alpha <- ifelse(data$time == max(data$time), 1, NA)
## initialize inds
inds <- 1
## continue to loop while inds has any values in it
while(length(inds) > 0){
  ## identify points where alpha==NA and the parent is among the parents where alpha == 1 or the offspring are among the parents where alpha == 1
  inds <- which(is.na(data$alpha) & (data$parent %in% data$parent[which(data$alpha == 1)] | data$offspring %in% data$parent[which(data$alpha == 1)])
  ## replace those observations' alpha values with 1
  data$alpha[inds] <- 1
  ## continue to loop back through generations
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Dave. I highly appreciate that you spend some time on my issue. I realised that my raw data is a lot more complicated than my sample, but your answer helped me to think of a solution. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

This might help :

```
#Assign `NA` to new column
data$alpha <- NA  
#get the parent value at max time period
parent <- unique(na.omit(data$parent[data$time == max(data$time)]))
#Change those values 1 wherever those value exist (offspring or parent)
data$alpha[data$parent %in% parent | data$offspring %in% parent] <- 1
data

#  time parent offspring alpha
#1    0      1        NA     1
#2    0      2        NA    NA
#3    0      3        NA    NA
#4    1      1         4     1
#5    1      1         5     1
#6    1      2         6    NA
#7    2      1         7     1
#8    2      4         8     1
#9    2      5         9     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ronak. You have always been helpful. I appreciate the neat solution and your nice explanation of the code.